# Hadoop 2.5.2 slow responsiveness

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I've setup `Hadoop 2.5.2` is pseudo distributed mode according the the documentation on a MacBook  pro w/16GB ram currently running `OS X 10.9.5`.

Everything seems to be working, but ***the issue*** is that it's extremely slow.

- `start-dfs.sh` takes a 3-5 minutes to start namenodes
- `hdfs dfs -ls /` takes about a minute or two to run.

I've ingested no data, and haven't done anything outside the documentation.
I've tried `export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER=DEBUG`,  but I'm not getting any extra output, or am seeing anything unusual in the logs. Perhaps I'm not looking at the right place.

The only error I ever see, which I've always seen with older versions of hadoop is:

```
"Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore"
```

Any ideas on why everything might be so slow? Also, according to my Activity Monitor, I'm barely using any resources.

I just noticed this in my namenode log when I run the `dfs -ls`

```
2014-11-25 11:47:24,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Scanned 0 directive(s) and 0 block(s) in 1 millisecond(s).
2014-11-25 11:47:54,063 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Rescanning after 30000 milliseconds
2014-11-25 11:47:54,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Scanned 0 directive(s) and 0 block(s) in 1 millisecond(s).
2014-11-25 11:48:24,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Rescanning after 30001 milliseconds
2014-11-25 11:48:24,064 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Scanned 0 directive(s) and 0 block(s) in 0 millisecond(s).
2014-11-25 11:48:54,065 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.CacheReplicationMonitor: Rescanning after 30001 milliseconds
```

**Configurations**

core-site:

> ```
> <configuration>
>   <property>
>         <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
>         <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
>     </property>
> </configuration>
> ```

hdfs-site:

> ```
> <configuration>
>    <property>
>       <name>dfs.replication</name>
>       <value>1</value>
>    </property>
> </configuration>
> ```

**NameNode**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With nothing else to try, I decided to try removing the  "Unable to load realm info from SCDynamicStore" warning. The solution to that was to set HADOOP_OPTS.

Although doing the following did NOT remove the warning, it for some reason FIXED my speed issue.

```
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Djava.security.krb5.realm=OX.AC.UK
-Djava.security.krb5.kdc=kdc0.ox.ac.uk:kdc1.ox.ac.uk"
```

If anyone can explain why, I'll definitely accept that answer.

Comment: I've since updated to different versions of pretty much everything, and haven't had this issue again.